# how to customize pub.dev package and use it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

We want to change and edit a package for flutter or dart .
How should we do this and use this package on own projects?
I'm planning to fork it from the GitHub source.
What do you think should be done next?

Comment: What is the actual problem you have run into? Seems to me you should just mimic what others have done and then see where that gets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugin1.git
```

See [Dependencies on unpublished packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages) for details.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for multiple projects was copying the codes from the package into my project directory and then edit it according to my need, removing all unnecessary codes if it is not needed in my application.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want to use that edited package for a few other projects of mine and my colleagues in the future.  And at the same time, I will update it many times and give it to them.  .  (In private mode)